# Flag employees based on joining two tables

Tags: oracle

I have two tables, table A (2 rows) and table B (3 rows) which are joined based on common identifier as shown below.

[image: table A]

[image: table B]

On doing the inner join based on seeker_id, I get 6 records for both seeker_program_id 6261708 and 6459364 i.e. 3 records for each seeker_program_id , because we've 3 rows in second table B.

Below is the query I've written:

```sql
select t.*, qe.year, qe.quarter_nbr, 
case 
    when t.qae1 = qe.QUARTER_NBR || qe.year and qe.QUARTERLY_EARNINGS_AMT not in('99999.99', '0') then 1 else 0 end as QAE1_Emp,
case
    when t.qae2 = qe.QUARTER_NBR || qe.year and qe.QUARTERLY_EARNINGS_AMT not in('99999.99', '0') then 1 else 0 end as QAE2_Emp,
case
    when t.qae3 = qe.QUARTER_NBR || qe.year and qe.QUARTERLY_EARNINGS_AMT not in('99999.99', '0') then 1 else 0 end as QAE3_Emp,
case
    when t.qae4 = qe.QUARTER_NBR || qe.year and qe.QUARTERLY_EARNINGS_AMT not in('99999.99', '0') then 1 else 0 end as QAE4_Emp
from temp_outcome t, QUARTERLY_EARNINGS qe
where t.seeker_id = qe.seeker_id
and qe.year in ('2019', '2020');`
```

[image: current output]

My desired output is to not get duplicate rows because of the inner join with second table B.

Below is my desired output.

[image: desired output]

How do I get rid of the duplicates and update the flags at the same time?

Comment: sorry, forgot to add query I've written -

Comment: Please edit your question to properly format all of your text, including tables and sample data. Formatted text is super-important to include, instead of images of text. This [meta post](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/285557/272109) lists many reasons why this is important. Also, it's very difficult to read your SQL query the way it's presented as one long continuous string. That can be formatted properly as well.

Comment: I fixed your sql formatting. You'll still need to edit to add properly-formatted text for your tables and output.

Comment: @DavidMakogon - thanks a lot for formatting my query.  This was my very first post and I've learnt from my mistake

Answer (score 0):

Since there are 2 times same seeker_id NJ%666 in the first table and 3 times same seeker in another - there is no way to filter duplicates out when joining tables.

The condition

```
where t.seeker_id = qe.seeker_id
```

means "dear database take all the entries with seeker "NJ%666" from the table t and join every one of them with every single row from qe table that have same seeker". Thus, it gives you 3x2=6 rows in the output.

That rows are not completely duplicates though, columns starting from "QUARTER_NBR" differ from line to line. Which lines are to be considered as duplicates then?

Answer (score 0):

I got the query working for me. I guess, I just need a break ;)

```sql
select t.*
,case when t.QAE1 in (select QUARTER_NBR||year from QUARTERLY_EARNINGS q where t.seeker_id = q.seeker_id) THEN 1 ELSE 0 END AS QAE1_EMP
,case when t.QAE2 in (select QUARTER_NBR||year from QUARTERLY_EARNINGS q where t.seeker_id = q.seeker_id) THEN 1 ELSE 0 END AS QAE2_EMP
,case when t.QAE3 in (select QUARTER_NBR||year from QUARTERLY_EARNINGS q where t.seeker_id = q.seeker_id) THEN 1 ELSE 0 END AS QAE3_EMP
,case when t.QAE4 in (select QUARTER_NBR||year from QUARTERLY_EARNINGS q where t.seeker_id = q.seeker_id) THEN 1 ELSE 0 END AS QAE4_EMP
from (select distinct sp.seeker_program_id, sp.seeker_id, sp.program_id, sp.registration_date, sp.termination_date
, to_char(sp.termination_date, 'Q') as T_Qtr
, extract(year from sp.termination_date) as T_Year
, to_char(sp.termination_date, 'Q') || extract(year from sp.termination_date) as QE
, to_char(to_date(to_char(add_months(trunc(sp.termination_date, 'Q'), 3))), 'Q') as QAE
, extract(year from to_date(to_char(add_months(trunc(sp.termination_date, 'Q'), 3)))) as YAE
, to_char(to_date(to_char(add_months(trunc(sp.termination_date, 'Q'), 3))), 'Q') || extract(year from to_date(to_char(add_months(trunc(sp.termination_date, 'Q'), 3)))) as QAE1
, to_char(to_date(to_char(add_months(trunc(sp.termination_date, 'Q'), 6))), 'Q') || extract(year from to_date(to_char(add_months(trunc(sp.termination_date, 'Q'), 6)))) as QAE2
, to_char(to_date(to_char(add_months(trunc(sp.termination_date, 'Q'), 9))), 'Q') || extract(year from to_date(to_char(add_months(trunc(sp.termination_date, 'Q'), 9)))) as QAE3
, to_char(to_date(to_char(add_months(trunc(sp.termination_date, 'Q'), 12))), 'Q') || extract(year from to_date(to_char(add_months(trunc(sp.termination_date, 'Q'), 12)))) as QAE4
from seeker_program sp
where 
termination_date  >= to_date('01012019','MMDDYYYY') and --PY Start
termination_date <= to_date('12312019','MMDDYYYY')  --PY End
--sp.termination_date is not null 
and sp.seeker_id in ('NJ000000666', 'NJ000564145')
) t;
```